Bootstrap 5: input-group with a Glyphicon?
In BS3, I could add a Glyphicon to an input-group with input-group-addon (jsfiddle):
<div class="row">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="idPassphrase">Passphrase</label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="idPassphrase" class="form-control input-xs" type="password" autocomplete="off">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

This shows a password entry field, with an open/close eye icon to view or hide the password.
How do I do this in Bootstrap 5? There doesn't seem to be an input-group-addon any more. The input-group docs don't have any examples with graphics of any sort - the only option appears to be input-group-text.

Your question isn't clear. Icons typically are text these days--they're often font libraries. Put whatever icon you want in place of the text.

Be sure to follow the current docs instead of the very old 5.0 docs.

In BS5 icons are an independent package. See icons.getbootstrap.com. After including both stylesheets (icons and regular bs) you can use them as follows


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="idPassphrase">Passphrase</label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="idPassphrase" class="form-control input-xs" type="password" autocomplete="off">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-eye-slash"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



